# ZF2 Sql using named parameters

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2, named-parameters

Is it possible to use named parameters in a Select, Update or Delete query object in Zend Framework 2? e.g.

```
$myValue = 'FooBar';

$sql = new Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select('my_table')
              ->where('my_column = :my_value')
              ->setParameter('my_value', $myValue);
```

Comment: voting down is all well a good, but with out a reason to improve the question it's just unhelpful

Comment: I really don't find a reason to votedown this question!!! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never done this but found the answer on an older version of ZEND
[here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.statement.html)

So to answer your question yes it is possible. As it is explained on the website provided.
"If you use named parameters, or those that are indicated by a string identifier preceded by a colon character (':'), pass the bind values in an associative array. The keys of this array should match the parameter names. "

```
$select = $sql->select('my_table')
                      ->where('my_coumn = :my_value');
                      //->setParameter('my_value', $myValue);

        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $statement->execute((array(':my_value' => 'FooBar')));//you pass named parameters here in an associative array
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->initialize($result);

        return $resultSet->toArray();
```

Good Luck Mate.

Comment: Yes, parameters are set in the same way in ZF2